# How to passed variable by value not by reference as argument to function in dart?

Tags: function, reference, arguments

By default, in below code, variable is passed by reference to function, but how to passed the variable by value in dart ?

```
// Dart 2.6.1
void func(List inp){
    inp[0]=1000;
}
main() {
    var a=[0,0,0];
    print(a);
    func(a);
    print(a);
}
```

output:

[0, 0, 0]

[1000, 0, 0]

Process finished.

Comment: your question is not very clear. can you tell me the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

your question is not quite clear. but i think you mean to copy a list.
if your expected output to this code is

output:

[0, 0, 0]

[0, 0, 0]

then use List.from to copy a list without making it a reference

```
void func(List inp){
  List x=new List.from(inp);  
  x[0]=1000;
}

main() {
    var a=[0,0,0];
    print(a);
    func(a);
    print(a);
}
```